# Authentication Strategy using Torii for Ember CLI 'static' apps

Tags: ember.js, torii

Just to clarify my understanding of what Torii provides for client side static apps:

- OAuth 2.0's Implicit Grant workflow is the only OAuth workflow which works in client side static apps.
- Torii only supports this via **torii/providers/oauth2-bearer**, which returns tokens not codes.
- If 1. and 2. are true, then I suppose all client side static apps which use Torii would only use the [oauth2-bearer](https://github.com/Vestorly/torii/blob/master/lib/torii/providers/google-oauth2-bearer.js) approach. The rest of the providers in Torii, like **stripe-connect** etc. which are code workflow based would need server support to get an AccessToken based on the code.

Is this right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I use the azure-ad-provider to get openid-connect id_tokens. And I'm working on an integration with auth0 using openid-connect.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the concepts in Torii can be a little confusing to understand. Because it's so flexible, the answer to most questions is "it depends".

Your understanding is basically correct:

1. Yes, the only useful OAuth workflow which does not require a server with a shared secret is Implicit Grant.
2. Yes, the bearer provider does not require you to run a server. Neither does the facebook-connect provider, or any custom provider which uses the same approach.
3. Serverless apps using Torii cannot use an Authorization Code workflow, and would need an authentication mechanism which returns an access token. This is likely to be using the oauth2-bearer provider, but you could use facebook-connect or any other similar approach.